# Power Query search entire table, replace each cell value that contains specific string

Tags: powerquery, m

Write M code step that will replace, with a new value, the entire current value of each table cell that contains a specified string.

Comment: When you write such a question, make sure to show the work you've done rather than just proposing a task and asking for solution.

Comment: And please, don't ask us to solve your homework, test, or assignments tasks. This question reads like one of these. If you have to solve the task, I'm sure your course materials will cover the How. It's just a few clicks.

Comment: [This is the function you want](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/table-replacevalue).

Comment: Thanks, @greggyb, I try it.

Comment: @hash_purple : My apology for omitting any of my own coding attempt.  I'm new to M programming and simply not yet comfortable with writing my own code from scratch.  I thought if I could see a generic example of the syntax for the script of the step that I described, then I could replace the example object names with my particular ones.  Since opening this question, I did some more research and came across a post on "social.technet.microsoft.com...Power Query Find/Replace Values using wildcard string," that sounds like my issue, too. I'll get back.  Thanks!

Comment: I was able to recreate the "Proposed as answer by Gil RavivMVP on Thursday, March 5, 2015 9:35 AM" found among the long list of comments on the post that I mentioned above, namely, [Power Query Find/Replace Values using wildcard string](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/dc1aceb5-a1b1-49ee-82fe-bd421e067920/power-query-findreplace-values-using-wildcard-string).

Comment: However, the foregoing solution results in adding another column to the table that's being searched, and then the replacement value is being placed in the new column.  Instead, I want the replacement value put into the searched cell and replace the original contents in its entirety. And I want this search and replace operation performed on every cell in the table.

Comment: Here is a copy of the "almost there" code:

Comment: `let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Modified Values", each [Values]),
    replaceTextIfContainsABC = (inputText, old, new) =>
    
    if (inputText is text and Text.Contains(inputText, old)) then
            new
        else
            inputText,

    #"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Added Custom","ABC","ABC", replaceTextIfContainsABC, {"Modified Values"})
in
    #"Replaced Value"`

Comment: My apology for the crammed code segment above.  Though I read your stack-overflow markdown help page, I still don't know how your formatting parsing symbols operate.  Wouldn't mind if an admin reformatted it for me.  Thanks

Comment: I think I figured out the code to accomplish my original goal:<!-- language: M -->
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    replaceTextIfContainsABC = (inputText, old, new) =>
    
    if (inputText is text and Text.Contains(inputText, old)) then
            new
        else
            inputText,

    #"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(Source,"ABC","ABC",  replaceTextIfContainsABC,{"Values"})
in
    #"Replaced Value"

Answer (score 0):

let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    replaceTextIfContainsABC = (inputText, old, new) =>

```
if (inputText is text and Text.Contains(inputText, old)) then
        new
    else
        inputText,

#"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(Source,"ABC","ABC",  replaceTextIfContainsABC,{"Values"})
```

in
    #"Replaced Value"